# How can i extend AdapterViewAnimator or AdapterViewFlipper?

Tags: android, android-widget

how can i implement Stackview-like Widget? 
I think using Adapterview or GalleryWidget, But I wanna Circularable ListView..

So, using AdapterViewAnimator or AdapterViewFlipper.. how can i create layout?(overide method.. or implement code..)

Answer (score -1):

### update:

you can try CWAC EndlessAdapter in CommonsWare Android Components more in information is present in [Git Hub Project Page](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless)

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:endless:1.2.3'
}
```

### end update:

check this link and tell me if you find it useful.

[**Circular Gallery**](http://evgeni-shafran.blogspot.com/2011/08/tutorial-custom-gallery-circular-and.html)

Comment: @MikeLaren, updated the answer with more time proof resource. I just hope git hub will not go offline.